# My php project is not running on local ubuntu machine

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache2, ubuntu-13.04

**Php  project is working still yesterday.today when i open it shows 404 error.**
    in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ new swap file is appeared i removed and started the apache2 server again still it is not working.
    When i open logs it shows: caught SIGTERM, shutting down[notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
    **virtual host file**

```
<VirtualHost dev.eurofir:81>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName localhost:80
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev.eurofir/public
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/dev.eurofir/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all 
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Try to backup your project, reinstall your local server then try to run it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your /etc/host and provide me more information like httpd.conf and if you have any virtual host configuration

Comment: i have added my virtual host file details

Comment: here i have to add 81 instead of 80 at <VirtualHost dev.eurofir:81>
Thank you who tried to help me.. :)